# inserting records from specific columns in one table to another table depending on multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, insert

I'm Using SQL server and need to Inset records from one table into another empty table. the first table im pulling from is called accnt and has the fields: code, invno, invdate, ven, and amnt, and imported. the table that the records are going to is called quick and has the fields: date, num, name, account, split, and amount. some of the fields are just directly copied which i understand, but what im having trouble with is that some of the fields need to be populated with a different field from accnt depending on the value in account. **and there is a field in accnt called imported that is either empty or has an x in it. i only want to import records where the imported field is empty**

the insert statement i have so far should import: date, name, account, and amount directly not depending on the anything. But the num field imports from a different field in accnt depending on the value of the accno field. the criteria is:

if account < 7000 then num = code
if account > 7000 then num = invno

here is what i tried, but it didnt work

```
DELETE FROM quick
INSERT INTO quick (date, num, name, account, amount) 
if accnt.accno < '7000'
   then SELECT invdate, code, ven, accno, amnt from accnt
if accnt.accno > '7000'
   then SELECT invdate, invno, ven, accno, amnt from accnt
```

how do i accomplish what i'm trying to do? the table looks like this even though the data in the picture is wrong:

[image]

the type and split fields will be populated later with an update query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with a single SELECT and use CASE to separate the two situations.

```
DELETE FROM quick
INSERT INTO quick (date, num, name, account, amount) 
SELECT invdate,
case when accnt.accno < '7000' then code else invno end
, ven, accno, amnt from accnt
```

Comment: this works for the num column, but what about only inserting the records where the imported column is empty

Comment: Could you just add a WHERE clause for that to the end of what I wrote? WHERE imported IS NULL

Comment: yes. i dont know why i didnt think of that. running on too little sleep

Comment: Working overtime? You need a bigger team.